# Why doesn't udev automatically map my usb device to the usbhid driver on every system

Tags: usb, 19.10, 20.04, udev

I have 3 systems running Ubuntu 19.10.
I have a USB HID device which can be seen by each of those systems.
I am using the exact udev rules file on all 3 of them:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="XXXX",ATTRS{idProduct}=="YYYY",MODE="0660",GROUP="timothy",SYMLINK+="mydevice%n"

KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", MODE="0664", GROUP="timothy"
```

On all 3 sytems the device correctly shows up as /dev/mydevice...

If I run `lsusb -t` I will get the following on one system:

```
Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

As you can see the usbhid driver is mapped correctly here,
but on the other systems I get the following:

```
Port 2: Dev 1, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver= , 12M
```

On these systems the driver is not automatically mapped. Because of this
my software cannot see nor use the device.

I can manually assign the driver using

```
echo -n "4-3:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/bind
```

At which point `lsbusb -t` shows the following:

```
Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

Now my software can see the device but cannot open it.

I really cannot figure out why the device is correctly mapped on one system
but not on the others. I didn't do anything special to make it work on the
working system, just a clean install like the other two.
The only difference being that the working one is a desktop and the other two are laptops.

**Update 2**:
I verified that the device only works after it has been logically
disconnected and re-connected to the host. Currently I am doing this
by connecting it to the VMWARE guest and then reconnecting it to the host.
Is there another way to logically reconnect a device (as opposed to physically)

**Update 3**:
I can also verify this issue does not exist on Raspbian (RaspberryPI)
or Ubuntu 18.04. On those systems, when you connect the device the `hidusb` driver is always bound to it.

**Update 4**:

The rules file is located at `/etc/udev/rules.d/100.mydevice.rules`
and every time I connect one of those devices the dev file is created
under `/dev` for example `/dev/mydevice4`

(This part works every time on every system, but does not mean
I can actually use the device)

On Ubuntu 20.04 I seem to have a little more luck.
That is to say if it does work it keeps working until I reboot
the entire machine, and if it does not work it definitely wont
until I reboot the machine.

**udevadm info***

```
root@devtop-home:/home/timothy# udevadm info /dev/mydevice10 
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10
N: bus/usb/003/014
L: 0
S: mydevice10
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/003/014
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: PRODUCT=483/5750/200
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: BUSNUM=003
E: DEVNUM=014
E: MAJOR=189
E: MINOR=269
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=1354934046
E: ID_VENDOR=Acme
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Acme
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0483
E: ID_MODEL=mydevice_V2
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=mydevice\x20V2
E: ID_MODEL_ID=5750
E: ID_REVISION=0200
E: ID_SERIAL=Acme_mydevice_V2_3100079BDA31
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=3100079BDA31
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=STMicroelectronics
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=LED badge -- mini LED display -- 11x44
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_10
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/mydevice10
```

As you can see this is based on an STM32F4 MCU
When the device is powered on it needs some time before
HID is enabled in the firmware.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you add where did you put the rule: file name and its full path? Also `udevadm info ..` to collect attributes and environment variables for both systems. One thing from information currently available in the question. You may try, check device groups, `GROUP=` means overwrite of groups set by previous rules, try again with `GROUP+=` so it will not affect standard groups that already set by previous rules.

Comment: @user.dz I have added the location in the question now. Will try changing the group

Comment: @TimothyP Could you run this on different systems: `udevadm test -a add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10` use path from `udevadm info` output. Share outputs by uploading to http://paste.ubuntu.com  (you can use `pasteinit` tool for convenience) .  Output will show in which order the rules loaded and which one triggered. also we may compare the environment values.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xb2VW3vd9h/ As you can see the rules for mydevice are loaded

Comment: I asked the question with an account I created by accident. And I've been trying to get my accounts merged but the process fails every time so I can no longer edit this question.